# Embedded youtube video does not play in google chrome

Tags: html, youtube

I have embedded a youtube video in an html file using the iframe tag provided by youtube. The video thumbnail loads on page but upon clicking play, an error message appear " video not available"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Youtube video</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <iframe width="560" height="315" 
            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kw4tT7SCmaY" 
            frameborder="0" 
            allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; 
            gyroscope; picture-in-picture" 
            allowfullscreen>
            </iframe>     
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi...this video link is not working ...so it not appear in your ifram..ok you can try to open the link on your browser..

Answer (score 1):

There are one rule in youtube. You can not embedded any channel video. So you are trying to embedded the video of T-Series and T-series don't allow to others to embedded there video.